# Can the Tokina AT-X 165 PRO DX AF 16-50mm f/2.8 actually be found new, and how does it compare to the Canon EF-S 17-55mm f/2.8 IS USM?

Tags: lens, canon-60d, reviews, tokina

I am having difficulties finding in-depth (Canon mount) reviews and comparisons for the Tokina AT-X 165 PRO DX AF 16-50mm f/2.8 lens. This lens is currently not sold on Adorama and B&H says that is has been discontinued by the manufacturer. In fact many other sites state it is currently unavailable. However, on the [Tokina site](http://www.tokinalens.com/products/tokina/atx165prodx-a.html) it is called a "new" lens. I am confused.

In any case, suppose I could get this lens somewhere for roughly $550 - $600 USD, how does it compare with the $1100 - $1200 Canon EF-S 17-55mm f/2.8 IS USM? Does anyone have hands on experience with this lens?

Also, does anyone know of any reputable place that actually offers this lens?

Comment: Tokina website lists this Lens as being available as of May 2007...see specifications tab. Perhaps it is actually discontinued

Comment: Based on the bits and pieces of information it does not look like that the Canon mount was actually sold in North America.

Comment: As an alternative you might want to consider the Tamron 17-50mm f/2.8 I believe this goes for ~$450 for the non VR, ~$600 for the VR. The reviews I've seen have been positive. And lastly, I own the lens and personally endorse it. Though, not that my endorsement means anything. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Lenstip](http://www.lenstip.com/248.1-Lens_review-Tokina_AT-X_165_PRO_DX_AF_16-50_mm_f_2.8_-Introduction.html) has quite a complete review of the lens, they compare the canon to the nikon mount, even with some history: they mention how it was postponed after tokina realized how good the tamron was.

Tokina lenses can be hard to find, resellers only have the most recent ones available. Maybe you can find one in the second-hand market, that's how I found my Tokina 50-135 Canon mount not so long ago: clean, never unpacked, with a small premium.

In Japan though they seem to be well distributed, maybe you can find a shop there that will ship it to you.